# onscroll div in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

i want to build a div with scroll, that when you scroll this div, it will active anothe function.

i need to build this in a Object.

there is any way to do this?

---

*i write here an example source (that not work) of what i want.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onsc(divName, divChange) {
    this.play = function() {
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById(divName).onscroll = function() {
                this.scroll(n)
            }
        };
    }
    this.scroll = function(n) {
        document.getElementById(divChange).innerHTML = "you scroll!";
    }
}
c[1] = new onsc("div1", "div1_i").play();
</script>

<div id="div1_i">this div will change when you scroll</div>
<div id="div1" style="background:#C6E2FF; width:300px; height:200px; overflow-y:scroll;">
<p style="height:800px;">txt</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was nearly there. I made a few changes and put into a JSFiddle for you.

I added comments at what you missed. Most importantly the context of `this` changes when you entered into that function on the `onscroll` event.

**JavaScript**

```
function onsc(divName, divChange) {
    // First of all make `this` inherit to below functions
    var self = this;

    this.play = function () {
        document.getElementById(divName).onscroll = function() {
            // Changed this to call the parent and place the correct DIV
            self.scroll(divChange) 
        }
    }

    this.scroll = function (n) {
        document.getElementById(divChange).innerHTML = "you scroll!";
    }
}

c = new onsc("div1", "div1_i").play();
```

**Demo**

Have a look at my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bJD8w/2/

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52842627/9318764) and help me out. I think this code you wrote could be modified slightly to fit what I am trying to accomplish and have been unable to get help on.