# Pure CSS Parallax + Navigation Reveal on Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, html, parallax

So I've run into a problem involving pure CSS parallax in combination with a fixed navbar that changes size when the page begins to scroll or returns to the top. Each of the two parts work independently but when I combine them the parallax effect still works while the navbar does not change from it's initial state.

Here is the code for the parallax:

```css
main {
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2.25);
  background: url('https://faith.prismapixel.studio/assets/img/hero-desktop.jpg') top center / cover;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1;
}

section article {
  max-width: 75rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 7.5rem 0;
}

p {
  margin: 7.5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header class="section parallax">
    <h1>HEADLINE HERE</h1>
  </header>
  <section class="section static">
    <article>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

And here is the code for the navbar:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  yScroll()
};

function yScroll() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].className = "mini";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].className = "";
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0rem;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 23px;
  transition: height 0.3s ease 0s, opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav.mini {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 3rem;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2.25);
  background: url('https://faith.prismapixel.studio/assets/img/hero-desktop.jpg') top center / cover;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1;
}

section article {
  max-width: 75rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 7.5rem 0;
}

p {
  margin: 7.5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="">

</nav>
<main>
  <header class="section parallax">
    <h1>HEADLINE HERE</h1>
  </header>
  <section class="section static">
    <article>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

As you can see they both work fine on their own. If I remove the styling for the `<main>` tag, then the navbar will work but the parallax effect won't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems to be working? https://codepen.io/carolmckayau/pen/bmaJjL

Comment: @CarolMcKay the navbar works there but the parallax effect is not. The whole page is scrolling like a non-parallax page.

Comment: oh sorry, having a not so great morning.

Comment: @CarolMcKay No worries. This one is just beyond my skills as I'm not great with javascript yet. The problem appears to be in the perspective that is causing Event Listener to not register properly.

Comment: I worked it out, the javascript is relying on the body to scroll, but it is the <main> div that is scrolling INSTEAD, so, no body scroll no class "mini" added to the <nav>, in other words, the main div is stealing the scroll event from the body.

Comment: @CarolMcKay That's what I figured. So can I change `window` in `yPos = window.pageYOffset;` and `window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);` to the `<main>` element?

Comment: this might help, i don't have experience in it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of scouring the web and teaching myself more about javascript I have solved my dilemma.

```js
function yScroll() {
  var el = document.getElementById("main");
  var nav = document.getElementById("navBar");
  var y = el.scrollTop;
  if (y >= 50) {
    nav.className = "mini";
  } else {
    nav.className = "";
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  color: #212121;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 32rem;
}

body {
  font: normal 400 1.5rem 'Montserrat Alternates';
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overscroll-behavior-y: none;
}

nav {
  width: calc(100% - 1rem);
  height: 0rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 150ms ease 0s;
}

nav.mini {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  height: 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

#main {
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#main::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1rem;
}

#main::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 .5rem rgba(#212121, .5);
}

#main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

header {
  background: url('https://faith.prismapixel.studio/assets/img/hero-desktop.jpg') top center / cover;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2.25);
}

section {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1;
}

section article {
  max-width: 75rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 7.5rem 0;
}

p {
  margin: 7.5rem 0;
}

</style>
```

```html
<nav id="navBar" class="">
</nav>
<main id="main" onscroll="yScroll()">
  <header>
    <h1 id="print">Headline Here</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <article>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>ʻO Lorem Ipsum kahi haʻahaʻa wale nō o ka paʻi a me keʻano o nāʻoihana. ʻO Lorem Ipsum ka 'ōlelo papahana maʻamau o kaʻoihana o ka makahiki 1500, i ka wā i lawe ai kekahi mea paʻi kiʻiʻole i keʻano o ka type a scrambled iā ia e hana i kahi puke
        kiko'ī. ʻAʻole i ola wale i kaʻelima mau kenekulia, akā,ʻo ka leleʻana hoʻi i nāʻano o ka lolouila, e hoʻololiʻoleʻia ana. Ua hoʻolahaʻia i nā makahiki 1960 me ka hoʻokuʻuʻana i nā pepa Letraset i loko o nā moʻolelo Lorem Ipsum, a me nā mea hou
        aku me ka polokalamu hoʻopuka pākī e like me Aldus PageMaker me nā papa o Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

I had to modify the width of the navbar after solving my dilemma to accommodate the width of the scrollbar due to the scrollbar actually being on the `<main>` element and not the `<body>`. But that was easy to do.

I hope this helps anyone else trying to add a fixed reveal on scroll navbar to a pure CSS website.